# obtain Closed Form of Eigenvalues of a matrix by using a closed form of its eigenvalues' Determinant equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

$E$ is eigenvalues of $M_n$ if and only if $W_n=|M_n-E I_n|=0$ where $I_n$ is a $n-by-n$ identity matrix. I have a closed form of such equation as

$$W_n=(-1)^{n/2}(b_1-b_2^{n-2}V_1V_2)$$

when $n=2m$. Also, $b_1, b_2, V_1$and $V_2$ is real parameter. The initial condition is $W_1=V_2$.

How can I obtain the eigenvalues of such a matrix?

Comment: Your notation is confusing. Are you saying that $W_n = \det(M)$? If so, then what is the connection between $n$ and $M$? Is $n$ the size of the matrix $M$? Are you are you saying that $W_n=(-1)^{n/2}(b_1-b_2^{n-2}V_1V_2)$ and that $W_n = |M_n - EI_n|$, or is the second $W_n$ supposed to be a distinct quantity? What is $E$?

Comment: I think you mean *closed* form

Comment: @Ben Grossmann Thank you for your comment. I have edited it.

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @MiladJangjan It is strange that your formula for $|M-EI|$ does not contain an $E$. Do the constants in the formula depend on $E$?